# how to merge two data structure in python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, data-structures, iterator

I am having two complex data structure(i.e. _to and _from), I want to override the entity of _to with the same entity of _from. 
I have given this example.

```
# I am having two data structure _to and _from
# I want to override _to from _from
_to = {'host': 'test',
       'domain': [
           {
               'ssl': 0,
               'ssl_key': '',
           }
       ],
       'x': {}
       }
_from = {'status': 'on',
         'domain': [
             {
                 'ssl': 1,
                 'ssl_key': 'Xpyn4zqJEj61ChxOlz4PehMOuPMaxNnH5WUY',
                 'ssl_cert': 'nuyickK8uk4VxHissViL3O9dV7uGSLF62z52L4dAm78LeVdq'
             }
         ]
         }
### I want this output
_result = {'host': 'test',
           'status': 'on',
           'domain': [
               {
                   'ssl': 1,
                   'ssl_key': 'Xpyn4zqJEj61ChxOlz4PehMOuPMaxNnH5WUY',
                   'ssl_cert': 'nuyickK8uk4VxHissViL3O9dV7uGSLF62z52L4dAm78LeVdq'
               }
           ],
           'x': {}
           }
```

Use case 2:

```
_to = {'host': 'test',
       'domain': [
           {
               'ssl': 0,
               'ssl_key': '',
               'ssl_cert': 'nuyickK8uk4VxHissViL3O9dV7uGSLF62z52L4dAm78LeVdq',
               "abc": [],
               'https': 'no'
           }
       ],
       'x': {}
       }
_from = {
         'domain': [
             {
                 'ssl': 1,
                 'ssl_key': 'Xpyn4zqJEj61ChxOlz4PehMOuPMaxNnH5WUY',
                 'ssl_cert': 'nuyickK8uk4VxHissViL3O9dV7uGSLF62z52L4dAm78LeVdq'
             }
         ]
         }
```

dict.update(dict2) won't help me, because this will delete the extra keys in _to dict.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python append dictionary to dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930915/python-append-dictionary-to-dictionary)

Comment: thanks, I googled it, but I didn't find the same page. thanks for help

Answer (score 7):

It's quite simple:

```
_to.update(_from)
```

Comment: @user87005 - for use case 2 (which you have added after I posted my answer), it's not clear what should happen at the list level - if the list should be merged, updated (on which criteria).

Answer (score 1):

There's a trap as below:

```
_to = {'host': 'test',
       'domain': [
           {
               'ssl': 0,
               'ssl_key': '',
           }
       ],
       'x': {}
       }
_from = {'status': 'on',
         'domain': [
             {
                 'ssl': 1,
                 'ssl_cert': 'nuyickK8uk4VxHissViL3O9dV7uGSLF62z52L4dAm78LeVdq'
             }
         ]
         }
```

`_to['domain']['ssl_key']` omitted when `_to.update(_from)`
If you wanna a deep update, check [Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth)

Comment: The desired output is in the question.

Comment: looking into the post :) I have encountered same problem before @user87005