# How to create json by nesting two dictionaries

Tags: python

say I have two dictionaries; `orig` and `inner` how to create json object from them such that `inner` is embedded insider `orig`:

```
orig = {
   'A': 1,
   'B': 2,
   'C': 3
}

inner = {
   'D': 4,
   'E': 5
}

#embed inner insider orig
new = {
    'A': 1,
    'B': 2,
    'C': 3,
    'inner':{
              'D': 4,
              'E': 5
     }
}
```

Comment: Your new dictionary is invalid, nested dict has no key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930915/append-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: I just edited the question. Final object is supposed to be json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. There would be no value to access the inner dictionary from.

You could do:

```
new = {
    'A': 1,
    'B': 2,
    'C': 3,
    'inner': {
       'D': 4,
       'E': 5
    }
}
```

with: `orig['inner'] = inner` but with structure you posted there would be no way to access the inner dict.

Answer (score 1):

```
new=dict(orig)
new.update({"inner":inner})
```