# Python append Counter to Counter, like Python dictionary update

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter, python-collections

I have 2 Counters (Counter from collections), and I want to append one to the other, while the overlapping keys from the first counter would be ignored. Like the [dic.update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8930969/7252805) (python dictionaries update)

For example:

```
from collections import Counter
a = Counter(a=4, b=0, c=1)
b = Counter(z=1, b=2, c=3)
```

So something like (ignore overlapping keys from the first counter):

```
# a.update(b) 
Counter({'a':4, 'z':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
```

I guess I could always convert it to some kind of a dictionary and then convert it back to Counter, or use a condition. But I was wondering if there is a better option, because I'm using it on a pretty large data set.

Comment: I guess you could do `for key in b: if key not in a: a[key] = b[key]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Counter` is a `dict` subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), so you can explicitly invoke `dict.update` (rather than `Counter.update`) and pass two counters as the arguments:

```
a = Counter(a=4, b=0, c=1)
b = Counter(z=1, b=2, c=3)

dict.update(a, b)

print(a)
# Counter({'a': 4, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'z': 1})
```

Comment: well I tried it, but it returns a `NoneType`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @sheldonzy Of course. It modifies `a` in-place, so it doesn't have to return anything.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Oh smart, you call `dict.update` instead of `Counter.update`. Way more subtle than I thought at first, good job.

Comment: Why not use `a.update(b)`? I just checked and it works the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`dict unpacking`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html)

```
from collections import Counter
a = Counter(a=4, b=0, c=1)
b = Counter(z=1, b=2, c=3)
Counter({**a, **b})
Counter({'a': 4, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'z': 1})
```