# Merge 2 lists and remove duplicates in Python

Tags: python, django

I have 2 lists, looking like:

temp_data:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test (replaced)",
  "code": "test",
  "last_update": "2020-01-01",
  "online": false,
  "data": {
    "temperature": [
      {
        "date": "2019-12-17",
        "value": 23.652905748126333
      },
      ...
    ]}
```

hum_data:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test (replaced)",
  "code": "test",
  "last_update": "2020-01-01",
  "online": false,
  "data": {
    "humidity": [
      {
        "date": "2019-12-17",
        "value": 23.652905748126333
      },
      ...
    ]}
```

I need to merge the 2 lists to 1 without duplicating data. What is the easiest/efficient way? After merging, I want something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "code": "test",
  "last_update": "2020-01-01",
  "online": false,
  "data": {
    "temperature": [
      {
        "date": "2019-12-17",
        "value": 23.652905748126333
      },
      ...
    ],
    "humidity": [
      {
        "date": "2019-12-17",
        "value": 23.652905748126333
      },
      ...
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: which list you want to merge?

Comment: Do you want something like `data :{humidity:{[...]}, temperature:{[...]}}`  or `data{[...]}`?

Comment: @GabrielAvendaño I edited the question with a clear answer to your question :)

Comment: Are temp_data and hum_data in order?

Comment: I just had the error they are ReturnDict but my debugger says they are lists. They are in order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930915/append-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

If your lists hum_data and temp_data are not sorted then first sort them and then concatenate the dictionaries pair-wise.

```
# To make comparisons for sorting
compare_function = lambda value : value['id']

# sort arrays before to make later concatenation easier
temp_data.sort(key=compare_function)
hum_data.sort(key=compare_function)


combined_data = temp_data.copy()

# concatenate the dictionries using the update function
for hum_row, combined_row in zip(hum_data, combined_data):
    combined_row['data'].update(hum_row['data'])

# combined hum_data and temp_data
combined_data
```

If the lists are already sorted then you just need to concatenate dictionary by dictionary.

```
combined_data = temp_data.copy()

# concatenate the dictionries using the update function
for hum_row, combined_row in zip(hum_data, combined_data):
    combined_row['data'].update(hum_row['data'])

# combined hum_data and temp_data
combined_data
```

With that code I got the following result:

```
[
    {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'test (replaced)',
    'code': 'test',
    'last_update': '2020-01-01',
    'online': False,
    'data': {
        'temperature': [{'date': '2019-12-17', 'value': 1}],
        'humidity': [{'date': '2019-12-17', 'value': 1}]}
    },
    {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'test (replaced)',
    'code': 'test',
    'last_update': '2020-01-01',
    'online': False,
    'data': {
        'temperature': [{'date': '2019-12-17', 'value': 2}],
        'humidity': [{'date': '2019-12-17', 'value': 2}]}
    }
]
```