# Append dictionary in json using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, append

I am doing my first Python program and its Hangman game. I managed to make it work but as a part of the task I need to write "best results -hall of fame" table as json file. Each entry in the table should consist of name of the person and the result they achieved (number of tries before guessing a word). My idea is to use dictionary for that purpose and to append the result of each game to that same dictionary.

My code goes like this:

```
with open("hall.json","a") as django:
    json.dump(hall_of_fame, django)
```

hall_of_fame is a dictionary  where after playing a game the result is saved in the form of `{john:5}`

The problem I have is that after playing several games my .json file looks like this:

```
{john:5}{ana:7}{mary:3}{jim:1}{willie:6}
```

instead I want to get .json file to look like this:

```
{john:5,ana:7,mary:3,jim:1,willie:6}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please take a look?

Comment: It's difficult to imagine how you could end up with either of those json files since they are not valid json. I will also be difficult to help with the problem if you don't show any code other than the code you are using to save the data.

Comment: @Mark is it because the file is being opened in "a" mode (append) which would generate a file like that. which appends the item not changing the total structure of the previous item

Comment: Generally, load the whole JSON file (if present), modify data and write (not append) it to the file as a whole.

Comment: Thank you guys. Will try out everything said. Mark, I didn˛t post the whole code because I think it would be confusing since input menus are in different language. If I don`t figure this out, I will translate all and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should read your old json content. then append new item to it. an finally write it to your json file again. use code below:

```
with open ("hall.json") as f:
    dct=json.load(f)

#add new item to dct
dct.update(hall_of_fame)

#write new dct to json file
with open("hall.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(dct,f)
```

have fun :)

Comment: Thanks nariman. I tried what you suggested but it looks like ".update" is not recognized as a function. Do I need to load some library?

Comment: hi there. you should put a dictionary in your json file first. even an empty one.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930915/append-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary

Comment: Still doesnt work. .update has white letters in Visual studio. When I hoover mouse over the .update it says "update : Any" and when running the code it says:

Comment: This is what it gives when running the code Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\roso\Desktop\Python\hangman.py", line 82, in <module>
    f.dump(dct,f)
    ^^^^^^
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'dump'

Comment: turn it to json.dump(dct,f)    like my code above

Comment: Nariman, I get this errors

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dkolaric\Desktop\Python\ File "c:\Users\dkolaric\Desktop\Python\hangman.py", line 77, in <module>
    dct=json.load(f)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rosohatica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rosohatica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

Comment: File "C:\Users\ Rosohatica \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ Rosohatica \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @Rosohatica befor you run your code you should create hall.json file and inside it you just put { } as an empty dictionary.

Comment: nariman thanks, your code worked at the end :) I redid everything and I must have been doing something wrong before.